# Using Webpacker with Rails 5.1 on Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am following the instructions here: https://github.com/rails/webpacker to use Webpacker with React on Windows 10. In one terminal I run `ruby bin\rails server`, and in another `ruby bin\webpack-dev-server`, which gives the following error:

`bin/webpack-dev-server:31:inexec': Invalid argument - NODE_PATH=C:/Users/user/myapp/node_modules C:/Users/user/myapp/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --progress --color --config C:/Users/user/myapp/config/webpack/development.server.js (Errno::EINVAL)
from bin/webpack-dev-server:31:in block in <main>' from bin/webpack-dev-server:30:inchdir'
from bin/webpack-dev-server:30:in <main>'` Are further configuration steps needed in order to use Webpacker on Windows 10?